# Not able to use lightning:navigation in a lightening component rendered in a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, cti

I am rendering a Visualforce Page in the call center for my salesforce CTI.
On this Visualforce Page, i am rendering a lightening component.

In this lightening component i am using `lightning:navigation`, to navigate and open the detail pages of Case/Contact, when needed

In my component i have defined `lightning:navigation` like this -

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService" />
```

To open the pages, i am using it like this in the controller -

```
 var navService = params.component.find('navService');
  var pageReference = {
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
      actionName: 'view',
      recordId: payload.id,
    },
  };
  navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

This code works fine for navigation if i render this lightening component directly somewhere.

But when i render this component in a Visualforce Page, then this navigation does not work. There is no error or api calls in network.

I understand this might be happening because the Visualforce Page renders in an iframe, so now the lightening component is rendering in an iframe. So in that case, is there a way to navigate to another page in a VisualForce page?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Visualforce, use the [sforce.one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) commands, such as:

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject(payload.id);
```

Comment: for me sforce.one is coming as undefined. is there anyway to fix that?